# Is it possible to find integer solutions for this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just thought of something really crazy off the top of my head,

$$(2+3^{m/n})^{n/m}=(3+2^{n/m})^{m/n}.$$

Comment: Any pairs with $n = m$ will do.

Comment: Well, $\;n=m=1\;$ is one rather boring solution. What have you done so far?

Comment: To use mathematical symbols we use the language called Latex.

Comment: Eh, why did I not think of that?

Comment: what about this one? $$(2+2^{m/n})^{n/m}=(3+3^{n/m})^{m/n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

[Edited.]

Taking logs of both sides of your original equation, you get:

$$\frac{n}{m}\log(2 + 3^{m/n}) = \frac{m}{n}\log(3 + 2^{n/m}).$$

Re-arranging, we get:

$${\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)}^2 = \frac{\log(3 + 2^{n/m})}{\log(2 + 3^{m/n})}.$$

Let $x = n/m$.  We get:

$$x^2 = \frac{\log(3 + 2^x)}{\log(2 + 3^{1/x})}.$$

Using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%283+%2B+2%5Ex%29%2Flog%282+%2B+3%5E%281%2Fx%29%29), we see that the graph of

$$f(x) = \frac{\log(3 + 2^x)}{\log(2 + 3^{1/x})}$$

intersects that of

$$g(x) = x^2$$

at exactly $3$ points, one of them being $x = 1$.

Comment: If you let $x=n/m$ at the beginning and plug it into Wolfram Alpha, do you get the same three points?

Comment: @JonasMeyer, I think $x = 0$ will not be a solution but I was limited to a visual of the graph of $f(x)$ versus $g(x)$ when I wrote this answer.  And as far as I can remember, the graph appeared to pass through $x = 0$.